# Comparator as Oracle DECODE analog

Tags: java

I have some sql query:

`SELECT * FROM TASK ORDER BY DECODE(NUMBER,1,1,9,2,2,3,0);`

This query uses the decode sorting function from oracle.

In my app I use JPA and I want sort it in java code using comaparator. I have this code:

```java
users.getTasks().stream()
.sorted((o1, o2) -> {
    //  o1.getNumber()
    //  o2.getNumber()
})
```

`getTasks()` return list of `TASK` table mapping.

How can I repeat exactly the same sort in the comparator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle [`DECODE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function "replaces" values of `number` field with other numbers similar to switch statement:

```java
// class UtilSort
public static int getOrder(Task task) { 
    switch (task.getNumber()) {
        case 1: return 1;
        case 9: return 2;
        case 2: return 3;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Then it is possible to use this function in lambda or using method reference to sort tasks using [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```java
users.getTasks()
     .stream()
     .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(UtilSort.getOrder(a), UtilSort.getOrder(b)))
     ...
;

// or using method reference along with Comparator.comparingInt
users.getTasks()
     .stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(UtilSort::getOrder))
     ...
;
```